# import error OpenCV on Jupyter Notebook (but it works in Ipython on Terminal..)

Tags: python, opencv, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm having an interesting error where I could `import cv2` in Ipython on Terminal but cannnot import the library on Jupyter notebook. I checked the kernel but I'm using the same kernel (Anaconda python2.7)

Would someone has any idea how to fix this?

```
Error:
    ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-2-52da0154cfe4> in <module>()
    ----> 1 import cv2
          2 import numpy as np

    ImportError: No module named cv2
```

$import os
$os.sys.path

```
['',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/kn/.ipython']
```

$which python

```
/Users/kn/anaconda2/envs/python2/bin/python
```

Comment: What are `sys.executable` and `sys.path` in the interpreter where you *can* import cv2? What does `print(cv2)` show?

Answer (score 0):

Create a one-line `opencv.pth` file under `/Users/kn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

The content of that file is like:

```
/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This will append the `opencv3` path under all conda environments permanently. I think it's better than just make cv2 available for `python2` environment.